# Regroup array values using dynamic keys (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have this array, but it has duplicate values.

```
 $syncData = array(
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "1",
                "orgUnitName" => "josh",
                "sive" => "OK",
                "siim" => null,
                "hosp"=>null,
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "1",
                "orgUnitName" => "josh",
                "sive" => null,
                "siim" => "ERROR",
                "hosp" => null,
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "1",
                "orgUnitName" => "josh",
                "sive" => null,
                "siim" => null,
                "hosp" => "OK",
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "2",
                "orgUnitName" => "Bill",
                "sive" => "OK",
                "siim" => null,
                "hosp" => null,
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "2",
                "orgUnitName" => "Bill",
                "sive" => null,
                "siim" => "ERROR",
                "hosp" => null,
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "2",
                "orgUnitName" => "Bill",
                "sive" => null,
                "siim" => null,
                "hosp" => "ERROR",
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
          
        );
```

The orgUnitId, orgUnitName are repeated and different objects.
I want the values of sive, siim and hosp to be placed in a single object as shown below.

```
 $syncData = array(           
            (object)[
                
                "orgUnitId" => "1",
                "orgUnitName" => "josh",
                "sive" => OK,
                "siim" => "ERROR",
                "hosp" => "OK",
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],           
            (object)[
               
                "orgUnitId" => "2",
                "orgUnitName" => "Bill",
                "sive" => "OK",
                "siim" => "ERROR",
                "hosp" => "ERROR",
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
          
        );
```

But the keys sive, siim and hosp are dynamic, ie they come from another array as shown below.

```
   $serversList = array(
          (object)[
            "name"=> "sive"
          ],
           (object)[
            "name"=>  "siim"
           ],
            (object)[
            "name" =>  "hosp"
            ]
        );
```

But to know the keys sive, siim and hosp you must use another array. Because they are dynamic, that is, they can change their quantity (sive, siim , hosp, deco, hub).
Example: we can have:

```
  (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "2",
                "orgUnitName" => "Bill",
                "sive" => null,
                "siim" => null,
                "hosp" => "ERROR",
                "deco" =>  null,
                 "hub" => null
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
```

I tried this but it doesent work

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < (count($syncData)-1); $i++) {
            foreach ($serversList as $serverkey => $serverValue) {
              if($syncData[$i]->{$serverValue->name}==null){
                    $val= $syncData[$i];
                    $val->{$serverValue->name}= $syncData[$i + 1]->{$serverValue->name};
                    array_push($data_copy,$val);
              }
            }
        }
```

I get this result:

```
 $syncData = array(
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "1",
                "orgUnitName" => "josh",
                "sive" => "OK",
                "siim" => "ERROR",
                "hosp"=>null,
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "1",
                "orgUnitName" => "josh",
                "sive" => null,
                "siim" => "ERROR",
                "hosp" => "ERROR",
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "1",
                "orgUnitName" => "josh",
                "sive" => "OK",
                "siim" => null,
                "hosp" => "ERROR",
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "2",
                "orgUnitName" => "Bill",
                "sive" => "OK",
                "siim" => null,
                "hosp" => null,
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "2",
                "orgUnitName" => "Bill",
                "sive" => null,
                "siim" => "ERROR",
                "hosp" => null,
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
            (object)[
                "orgUnitId" => "2",
                "orgUnitName" => "Bill",
                "sive" => null,
                "siim" => null,
                "hosp" => "ERROR",
                "date" => "2023-01-19 00:00:00"
            ],
          
        );
```

Comment: Is the orgUnitId enough to identify what belongs together here, or does it need to be used in combination with the orgUnitName? (Meaning, could you also have unit=1 name=josh, and unit=1 name=bill?)

Comment: Yes the both orgUnitId and orgName are needed. I have to combine them

Comment: And how exactly are those "dynamic keys" relevant? Do you want to drop any other properties (besides id, name and date) from the resulting objects? Because right now, I don't see how that info was actually needed - just putting any property value that is _not_ null, into the resulting object, should be enough?

Comment: The main problem its that the $syncData array objects are created using the  $serversList. The orgUnitName, orgUnitId, date are  keys that each object will have by default. But the other keys will depend on  $serversList  names.
If  $serversList have 2 items ( name=> sive, name=>hosp) then each object in the $syncData array will have the default keys and those 2 sive and hosp. 
If  $serversList have 3 items then $syncDat will have the default and those 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like this are always quite easy to do, when you use a "helper" array, in that you insert the items under whatever the grouping "key" is.

Here that grouping key is the combination of unit id and unit name - so I am sticking both into an array and encode that as JSON, so that both values combined result in one *string* value, that we can use as array key.

Then we can go "look up" whether the item already exists in our helper array, and only needs additional properties added to it, or if we need to create it.

And `array_values` resets those keys to a normal, zero-based numeric index again afterwards.

```
$helper = [];
foreach ($syncData as $item) {
    $key = json_encode([$item->orgUnitId, $item->orgUnitName]);
    foreach ($serversList as $serverValue) {
        if(!isset($helper[$key])) {
            $helper[$key] = (object) [
                'orgUnitId' => $item->orgUnitId,
                'orgUnitName' => $item->orgUnitName,
                'date' => $item->date,
            ];
        }
        if ($item->{$serverValue->name} !== null) {
            $helper[$key]->{$serverValue->name} = $item->{$serverValue->name};
        }
    }
}
$helper = array_values($helper);

print_r($helper);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [orgUnitId] => 1
            [orgUnitName] => josh
            [date] => 2023-01-19 00:00:00
            [sive] => OK
            [siim] => ERROR
            [hosp] => OK
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [orgUnitId] => 2
            [orgUnitName] => Bill
            [date] => 2023-01-19 00:00:00
            [sive] => OK
            [siim] => ERROR
            [hosp] => ERROR
        )

)
```

You'll note that the order of the properties is a bit different (date moved up, due to when it got added) - but I suppose that should probably not matter much? (If it *does*, you could work with an array instead of objects, then sort those arrays by key in the desired order afterwards, and only then cast them into stdClass objects again.)

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.

The order of the properties doent matter.